# Datetime sorting in the gridview

Tags: c#

here i sort the datetime using this code

```
var query = from a in PurchaseRequestDetails.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

orderby DateTime.Parse(a.Field<string>("RequiredDate")) // this will sort ur data according to datetime

select a;

DataView view = PurchaseRequestDetails.Tables[0].AsDataView();

view.Sort = "RequiredDate";

dgvPurReq.DataSource = view;

dgvPurReq.DataBind();
```

Note:Here 'RequiredDate' is varchar in the database

i am getting a output like this:

- 01-Aug-2010
- 03-Aug-2010
- 06-Aug-2010
- 23-Jun-2010

'Jun' should come before the 'aug' sorting should be done in the month and even in the year also.

Answer (score 0):

the do one thing from backend sort your date as per requirement. It will give you Jan - Dec sequence. order your date in your query and in grid view format your date in dd-mmm-yyyy format. For formatting datetime in grid , in row databound event, pick the cell of where date is located, and apply formatting something like this String.Format("dd-mmm-YYYY");